# Printing lists with unknown length

Tags: reason, reason-react

I've got a `list(string)` with an unknown length which I would like to render in my ReasonReact component. I've read that there is [no built-in support](http://2ality.com/2018/01/lists-arrays-reasonml.html#printing-lists) for printing complex data structures. But how would one go about rendering a list in its component in a pure functional way without using Javascript? I've found a [snippet](https://github.com/nickzuber/add-reason/blob/8923a336c579d9fab5ba71f79cd8192315bb971d/src/commands/utils.re#L25-L36) that achieves this using recursion on pattern matching. I presume there must be an easier way as this seems like a rather often-used operation.

The Javascript equivalent of what I'm trying to achieve is `Array.toString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, there are two steps you want accomplished:

1. To create a `string` out of the `list(string)`, preferably formatted in the same way `Array.toString` does, i.e. comma-separated without surrounding square brackets, and without using any JavaScript-specific APIs.
2. To render the string as a ReasonReact component.

#### Step 1: String conversion

This can be done using [`String.concat`](https://reasonml.github.io/api/String.html#VALconcat):

```rust
let myList = ["a", "b", "c"];
let myString = String.concat(", ", myList);
```

which will return `"a, b, c"`

#### Step 2: Render as ReasonReact component

Rendering strings in ReasonReact are done using `ReasonReact.string`. Here's a complete, runnable example of a component taking a prop `items` of type `list(string)` and rendering it in a `<span>` element.

```rust
module ListRenderer = {
  let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("ListRenderer");
  let make = (~items, _children) => {
    ...component,
    render: _self =>
      <span> {ReasonReact.string(String.concat(", ", items))} </span>
  };
};

ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<ListRenderer items=["a", "b", "c"] />, "preview");
```

[Playground link](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=LYewJgrgNgpgBAGQJYGcAuAlGA7MMBOBcAvHAN4BQccsacAxiMAA4jY52lYCGKbP9NADp03NDFgoUAYSat22NAAoARMnRZcBAioCUAbio0YdYNwDW8UkoB%20SccBQAaOAH16ACyRQwhbLpIAPnIjaiFwxhY2DidQuD88fAAuNxQJADMguOoAHhRmbmxgsh4%20bAFhdHwkbABzJQBlNGq6oUZsejFVFxUXexhHXV0AXzgcgHp8wsCjYcM5igoKgBEAeQBZLCEEggAVEABRWGAOAHV7DwBJMCUc9UwcRKJ%20x2IAbRVuXrgVACNvlT0FQAXTg40CPWYhAAbkgYAB3PT6IA)

Comment: I was totally getting at this the wrong way, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot once again!!